# AngularJS directives - isolated scope special binding characters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

When declaring an isolated scope in an Angular directive, there are various special characters that are used to define how an attribute value maps to the directive's scope - for example '=' or '&'.  There used to be a handy list in the docs (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) explaining the use of these special characters but unfortunately that list seems to be gone!

So the question is what are these special characters and what do they mean?

Comment: I can see why this was down voted, but part of the problem is that I don't know what to call these "special characters" - so how could I search the documentation for them, save for reading the docs in their entirety?

Comment: This is an incredibly relevant question. This has been bugging me forever!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still find the list in the [$compile documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object).

Comment: Thanks, I knew it had to be somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

There are several explanations of AngularJS Directives on the Internet. There could be some here as well. From [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607873/Extending-HTML-with-AngularJS-Directives)

```
  name: "@",          // name var passed by value (string, one-way)
  amount: "=",        // amount var passed by reference (two-way)
  save: "&"           // save action
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607873/Extending-HTML-with-AngularJS-Directives

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS V1.5 adds one-way (`"<"`) binding:

```
"@" - Attribute Binding
"<" - One-way Binding
"=" - Two-way Binding (obsolete)
"&" - Expression binding
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based Application Architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture)